# Iphone app that will count up or down with voice

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation

I am in need of an iPhone app that will count down or up from a particular number for a visually impaired individual.

For example if 60 is entered a voice would say 60,59,58,57 and etc.

Does something like this exist for an iPhone 6?

Answer (score 1):

I found this app "Voice Over Timer" which looks to be configurable to do close to what you want.

AppStore Link: 
https://appsto.re/us/TeCFM.i

*edit* upon further review, it looks like the countdown can only be announced for the last ten seconds. The AppStore page mentioned a customization but it is a customization from among pre-determined options.

Comment: Thanks Kent. Yea, I had checked out that one and it doesn't appear to actually allow a count down from the start. I would have thought someone would have created something like this by now. My only alternative is to record my voice counting down/up :)

Answer (score -1):

"Stopwatch - simple with voice speaking time" - that's the full name.

Comment: Hi Ella, welcome to Ask Different. A link to the app and some description of how it resolves the problem presented by the OP would be great. Thanks!